# C# How to format Date ( DateTime)

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to get "Models.date_time" and execute "Foreach" for different days

Models.date_time  {
2020-04-19 14:55:44

2020-04-19 16:55:44

2020-04-20 8:55:44

2020-04-19 12:55:44 }

```
foreach (var TransactionsModelsSaleDate in Models.Select(x => X.date_time.ToShortDateString()).Distinct()) {

DateTime TestUtcBeginDate = DateTime.ParseExact(TransactionsModelsSaleDate, "yyyy/MM/dd/00/00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
DateTime  BeginDate = ...............
DateTime  EndDate   = ...............

                    }
```

But I need to format "TransactionsModelsSaleDate" to get BeginDate , EndDate.

```
TransactionsModelsSaleDate {


2020-04-19

2020-04-20  }


But I also need to get this information

BeginDate  => 

2020-04-19 AM 12:00 00 

2020-04-20 AM 12:00 00 


EndDate    =>

2020-04-19  23:59 00

2020-04-20  23:59 00
```

How can I do?

Thanke so much!!

Comment: I'm finding it very hard to understand your question. You've dumped a bunch of data in here, but with no explanation of what type it is, what you're trying to achieve etc. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: In addition to what Jon wrote, You should know that [DateTime have no format.](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/) In .Net, It is stored as the number of ticks since January 1st, 0001 at midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need list of dates you can select date part form DateTime

```
var list = Models.Select(x => X.date_time.Date).Distinct();

foreach (var TransactionsModelsSaleDate in list) {
}
```

Comment: This is the method I need!

Comment: But I need to convert (2020-04-19) date to 2020-04-19-00-00

Comment: you can use custom format as DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm") https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings